# C++ map an integer to an array of boolean

Tags: c++

I have been trying to create a map from integer to an array of bools. However, the following code does not seem to work.

```
map<int, bool[]> myMap;
bool one[] = {true, true, false};
myMap[1] = one;
```

I do not use array that much and there seems to be something seriously wrong here. Can someone point it out?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of saying: "the code does not work" try telling us what the code does, and what you expected it to do.  It helps us help you.

Comment: Arrays are not first class types in C++. [You can't use it like that](http://ideone.com/zpl3mh). [You must use a pointer](http://ideone.com/G8jiES) (or, even better, some proper container).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Storing an array like this in a `map` is not going to work, even if you could do it syntactically: the array is going to stay in the map even after the real array goes out of scope. Storing vectors of `bool` instead should work:

```
map<int, vector<bool> > myMap;
vector<bool> one {true, true, false}; // C++11 syntax
myMap[1] = one;
cout << myMap[1][0] << endl;
cout << myMap[1][1] << endl;
cout << myMap[1][2] << endl;
```

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/N0kvue).

Answer (score 2):

With C++0x, you may write like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <array>

int main() {
    std::map<int, std::array<bool, 3>> maparr {
        {1, {true, false, true}}, 
        {2, {false, false, true}}};

    for(auto& item: maparr) {
        for (auto& val : item.second) {
            std::cout << val << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output:

> 1 0 1
>
> 0 0 1

Since C++0x, we get a fixed size [array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).It may be what you are looking for.